# JSP with ORACLE table creation error

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, ojdbc

I am developing a application based on JSP web which should work with OJDBC.
Here TABLE name will be given by users within a FORM and table creation will be processed through a .jsp file linked with OJDBC.
BUT i am getting following error on  CREATETB.jsp

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /createdb.jsp at line 12

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page   /createtb.jsp at line 12

```
Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs;
rs = st.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE " + TbName  //LINE NO 12
+ "("
+ "A_IDD SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,"
+ "A_LASTT VARCHAR(25),"
```

MY index.jsp

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="createdb.jsp">
            <center>
            <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="3">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Create Table Here</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>NEW TABLE NAME</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="TbName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                      <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                      <td><input type="submit" value="Create" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

createtb.jsp

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%
    String TbName = request.getParameter("TbName");
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
            "paku", "paku");

    Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE " + TbName
            + "("
            + "A_IDD SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,"
            + "A_LASTT VARCHAR(25),"
            + "A_FF VARCHAR(20)"
            + ");");
    if (rs.next()) {
        out.println("TABLE CREATED ");
    } else {
        out.println("ERROR");
    }

%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at: [enter link description here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-tables.htm)
To create a table, you can't use:

```
Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs;
rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

because this is for select querys.
You rather have to use:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "CREATE TABLE "+table_name+" (...)"; 
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: ZeusNet thanks BUT this time error line 18  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

Comment: Don't forget to remove `;` from the end of your `CREATE TABLE` string. Also, create try/catch blocks and print exception StackTrace, it'll help you see what went wrong.

Comment: As timekiller mentioned the actual stacktrace would be helpful to solve your issue

Comment: Thank you @ZeusNet and Timekiller . problem solved by both of your answers :)